# NSArrayController's fetchPredicate not working as expected

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-data, nspredicate, nsarraycontroller

I write an app that uses Core Data to save friends. An NSTableView is supposed to show all friends, separated from each other depending on their status (online, offline, marked as favourite).
To fetch the specific friends for a section I use an NSArrayController.

In the following code you see what predicates I set on the specific array controllers.

```
_onlineFriendsController.fetchPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(favourite = NO || favourite = nil) && id in %@", self.onlineFriendsID];
_offlineFriendsController.fetchPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(favourite = NO || favourite = nil) && not (id in %@)", self.onlineFriendsID;
```

The `_onlineFriendsController` works as expected: It fetches the friends that are not favourited but online. However, the `_offlineFriendsController` doesn't work. It fetches all friends that are not favourited despite their availability.

I have also tried to set a predicate with a block to be able to debug it a bit better.

```
_offlineFriendsController.fetchPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
    if (![[evaluatedObject valueForKey:@"favourite"] boolValue]) {
        if (![self.onlineFriendsID containsObject:[evaluatedObject valueForKey:@"id"]]) {
            return YES;
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"%@", [evaluatedObject valueForKey:@"name"]);
    return NO;
}];
```

This returns NO for everyone who is online. It turns out that `_offlineFriendsController` fetched all friends anyway. What am I doing wrong? I have only set the controller's managedObjectContext, the sortDescriptors, the fetchPredicate and the entityName. 
What is the difference between filterPredicate and fetchPredicate anyways? filterPredicate just screws everything without actually doing something.

Any help is much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Try fire 

    [_arrayController fetch:someWhoFired];

or to wait (worked sometime, but I don't know why)

Comment: I had issues with fetchPredicate being nil even though I was setting it in viewDidLoad. The issue was with makeViewWithIdentifier: + tableview registerNib which was instantiating nib in the background it had somehow overridden my fetchPredicate (which was totally different instance of NSArrayController). Solution was to create separate NSNib for NSTableCellView